# php - What is quicker for search and replace in a csv file? In a string or in an array?

Tags: php, python, mysql, arrays, csv

I am dealing with csv files that usually have between 2 million to 5 million rows.  I have (for example) 3000 specific values that need to be replaced by 3000 different values.  I have two arrays of 3000 items called $search and $replace.  Note: The search and replace phrases are complete values (e.g. ...,search,... -> ...,replace,...).  Also, I'll eventually be importing this into a mysql database.

Which would be the most efficient/quickest way to accomplish this?

1. Load the entire contents of the csv file into a string and run str_replace using the arrays and the string
2. Load the csv file into arrays and use array_search() to replace the values
3. Load the csv file into a mysql database and then search and replace using queries
4. Use python instead
5. Other

I know I could setup some tests and compare their runtimes, but I'm more looking to understand why one is better than the other, or the mechanism by which they search (ex: O(n), binary search, etc.?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your csv file is that big (> 1 million rows), it might not be the best idea to load it all at once unless memory usage is of no concern to you.

Therefor, I'd recommend running the replace line by line. Here's a very basic example:

```
$input = fopen($inputFile, 'r');
$output = fopen($outputFile, 'r+');

while (!feof($input)) {
    $input = fgets($input);

    $parsed = str_replace($search, $replace, $input);

    fputs($output, $parsed);
}
```

This should be fast enough, and it allows you to easily track progress as well. If you would ever like to replace only specific column, you can use `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv` instead of `fgets` and `fputs`.

I definitely wouldn't try to do this using mysql, as simply inserting this much data into a database will take a while.

As for python, I'm not sure whether it can actually benefit the algorithm in any way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! I also agree that, from my experience, it has been better to process the data using php instead of importing and then via mysql.  While I know it is a lot of memory, I know the machine running this script has enough memory for this task, is not used for anything aside from this task, and will only be running one task at a time.  So I was initially using your line by line method (in memory, lines stored in an array, explode and implode to manage it) but I didn't know if a str_replace on the data as an entire string would be faster in memory or not.